# How to not show certain columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I have a question about discarding certain column in MySQL.

```
select 
data1.*, round(avg(data1.Yield),1) as Avg_Yield,round(avg(data1.Biomass),1) as Avg_Biomass,data2a.Height,data2a.Planting
from data1 right outer join data2a
on data1.Unique = data2a.Unique
group by data1.Fertilizer, data1.Genotype;
```

[image]

I summarized average data, and now I do not need to show **Yield** and **Biomass** columns because it makes me confused to see average data, **Avg_Yield** and **Avg_Biomass**

Maybe this could be a solution.

```
select 
data1.Plot_No,data1.Fertilizer,data1.Genotype,data1.Unique,
round(avg(data1.Yield),1) as Avg_Yield,round(avg(data1.Biomass),1) as Avg_Biomass,data2a.Height,data2a.Planting
from data1 right outer join data2a
on data1.Unique = data2a.Unique
group by data1.Fertilizer, data1.Genotype;
```

But, not typing all variables, I think there are more easy ways.

So, I'd like to not show these two columns. Could you tell me how I can do that?

Always many thanks!!

Comment: Your edit answered your own question, you select only the columns you need instead of *, there isn't a "select * except these columns" in SQL as far as I know.

Comment: "...But, not typing all variables, I think there are more easy ways..." -- Sorry, but you are out of luck. There have been efforts to add this functionality on other databases ("column selection algebra") but there's nothing yet done.

Comment: I voted to close this question as a duplicate. In the linked question, the criteria for excluding columns is different, but the answer is the same: if you use the `*` wildcard, this means _all columns,_ not all columns except those you don't want.

Comment: Thank you for your all comments!! I understood the logic. Always many thanks!! Stack Overflow is my best teacher!!